# iPhone SDK on MAC server

Tags: iphone

can I install iPhone SDK on mac server?
I want to upload iPhone project and compile it in the server is that possible at all.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

See: https://superuser.com/questions/15184/running-iphone-sdk-on-mac-os-x-server-in-vmware-on-a-pc

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for being late in accepting your answer